# Where are zsh's prompt presets located?

Tags: zsh, prompt

I'd like to create my own prompt but starting from one of the presets that can be obtained from `prompt -l`. I'd like to know where they're defined so I can duplicate one and pimp it.

Also, it'd be nice to know how to make the new prompt available as a choice in the list from `prompt -l` rather than just define it in .zshrc so it can be shared with communities.

p.s.: no I don't want to use oh-my-zsh

Comment: I'm not familiar with a `prompt` command in `zsh`, is it something in `oh-my-zsh`?

Comment: Hi there, thanks. Just as I was adding a comment :) ... I don't want to use zsh as it's another layer of things happening in my prompt. Prompts can be fancy without the total overkill that is oh-my-zsh and I don't feel any need to use it. Especially to do such a simple thing as customizing the prompt.

Comment: It's just that I can't find a `prompt` command anywhere in any package on Ubuntu or OpenBSD that seems to be related to `zsh`. What does this `prompt` command do and where is it from? What does `type -a prompt` output?

Comment: Have a look here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Zsh#Prompts scroll down to 'Configure zsh'. You should be able to get an output from `primpt -l` once you've called `autoload -Uz promptinit ; promptinit`

Comment: Can't you just set one prompt and then have a look at `$PS1` (and possibly `$RPS1`) and modify to what you want?

Comment: I might be wrong but in zsh prompt doesn't seem to be defined via environment variable. Infact `env` doesn't show anything about the prompt.

Comment: In the link I gave you I found information that I probably skipped before. There's a section called "Manually installing prompt themes" that's spot on.

Comment: Like most variables associated with how and what the shell does, they don't need to be exported (i.e. environment variables) since the shell have access to them anyway. Set a prompt and have a look at `$PS1`. Read the manual about the `PS1` variable and what the various things in it do.

Comment: `echo $PS1` does print out the prompt constructor line. That's useful, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This `prompt` command comes with zsh and is documented in the [manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html). It's unfortunately missing from the [functions index](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions-Index.html#Functions-Index), but you can find it with a full-text search: `man zshall` then search for `^ *prompt`  (the word “prompt” at the beginning of a line) or, to get fewer irrelevant hits, `^ *prompt [^ a-z]` (exclude places where it's followed by another word). It's part of the [prompt themes user contribution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Prompt-Themes).

The manual explains how to [write your own prompt theme](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Writing-Themes). A prompt theme is defined by a setup function matching the naming pattern `prompt_name_setup` which must be autoloaded. The prompt theme code doesn't officially support registering a prompt theme dynamically, though looking at the source code you can do it by adding the name of the setup function (which must match the naming pattern) to the `prompt_themes` array after running `promptinit`.

To see where the available prompt themes are, see where the `prompt_*_setup` functions are loaded from:

```
echo $^fpath/prompt_*_setup(N)
```

Each of these is a function definition which you can go and read.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
% autoload -Uz promptinit && promptinit  # Initialize the prompt system
% prompt -p                              # Preview the included prompts
...
% # Get the source file of a particular prompt:
% zmodload zsh/parameter
% print $functions_source[prompt_fade_setup]
/usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions/prompt_fade_setup
%
```